# Change status of an object after a set of async jobs is complete using sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, background-process, sidekiq

I'm using `sidekiq` to deal with async jobs, and after some complexity added, I'm having difficulties to be aware of the state of the jobs.

Here's the deal:

I have a model `Batch` that calls an async method after it's commited:

```
# app/models/batch.rb
class Batch < ActiveRecord::Base

  after_commit :calculate, on: :create

  def calculate
    job_id = BatchWorker.perform_async(self.id)

    # update_column skips callbacks and validations!
    self.update_column(:job_id, job_id)
  end
end
```

The worker reads data from the model and calls an async job for each data, as follows:

```
# app/workers/batch_worker.rb
class BatchWorker

  def perform(batch_id)
    batch = Batch.find(batch_id)

    ## read data to 'tab'    

    tab.each do |ts|
      obj = batch.item.create(name: ts[0], data: ts[1])
      job_id = ItemWorker.perform_async(obj.id)
      obj.update_attribute(:job_id, job_id)
    end
  end

end
```

The problem is: Those async jobs perform calculations, and I can't allow the download results link be available before it's complete, so I need to know when all "children-jobs" are done, so I can change a `status` attribute from the `Batch` model. In other words, I don't need to know if all jobs have been queued, but instead, if all async jobs generated by `ItemWorker` have been performed, and are now complete.

- What would be the best way to attain this? Does it make sense in the "parallel computation world"?

Obs.: I'm not sure about storing the job_id in db, since it seems to be volatile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps using Redis for this could be a good fit, seeing as you already have it in your infrastructure and configured in your Rails app (due to Sidekiq)

Redis has an inbuilt publish/subscribe engine, as well as atomic operations on keys - making it suitable for managing the type of concurrency you are looking for.

Maybe something roughly like this:

```
class BatchWorker

  def perform(batch_id)
    batch = Batch.find(batch_id)

    redis = Redis.new
    redis.set "jobs_remaining_#{batch_id}", tab.count
    redis.subscribe("batch_task_complete.#{batch_id}") do |on|
      on.message do |event, data|
        if redis.decr("jobs_remaining_#{batch_id}") < 1
          #UPDATE STATUS HERE
          redis.del "jobs_remaining_#{batch_id}"
        end
      end
    end

    tab.each do |ts|
      obj = batch.item.create(name: ts[0], data: ts[1])
      job_id = ItemWorker.perform_async(obj.id, batch_id)
    end
  end
end

class ItemWorker
  def perform item_id, batch_id=nil
    #DO STUFF
    if batch_id
      Redis.new.publish "batch_task_complete.#{batch_id}"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Yup! This is great, it can really solve my problem. However, it seems that once the interpreter reaches the subscribe block, it will never exit and continue to listen for messages. So the tab.each block that perform ItemWorker is never reached, and tasks are never executed. How can I work that around?

Comment: Move the creation of the ItemWorkers inside the subscribe block, after on.message do. When the jobs are all done, use a throw/catch to exit the block.

Comment: I actually moved the `redis.decr` to the ItemWorker, so every time a jobs is complete, it decreases the counter and check if it's `<1`. If it is, the ItemWorker itself changes the parent batch status, avoiding to use the subscribe block. Thanks! ;)